# Composing and outputting two future asynchronous actions on screen

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, action, future

I hate to ask - I really do but this one has got me for the moment..

I'm trying to compose some actions (in ***Play Framework*** & ***scala***) with my main guide being [this vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4b1XLka0UIw). However it was made a few years back so some of the functionality has since been deprecated and therefore I have had to find work-arounds as I go. Currently I am trying to output two asynchronous actions within some HTML markup.

I successfully outputted one action with this controller:

```
package controllers

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import javax.inject._
import play.api.mvc._
import services.ServiceClient
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

@Singleton
class AsyncController @Inject() (sc: ServiceClient)(actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller {

  def index = Action.async { request =>

    val asy1 = sc.makeServiceCall("async1")

    for {
      async1Message <- asy1
    } yield {
      Ok(views.html.async1.async1(async1Message))
    }
  }

}
```

In case you are wondering the `sc.makeServiceCall` refers to this file:

```
class ServiceClient @Inject() (ws: WSClient) {

  def makeServiceCall(serviceName: String): Future[String] = {
    ws.url(s"http://localhost:9000/mock/$serviceName").get().map(_.body)
  }

}
```

So I followed the video in its' guidance to compose two asynchronous actions with some HTML. And this is where it gets difficult/interesting/upsetting:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.Inject
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext}
import Ui.Pagelet

class AsyncHomeController @Inject() (as1: AsyncController)(as2: Async2Controller)(actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller {

  def index = Action.async { request =>

    val asy1 = as1.index(request)
    val asy2 = as2.index(request)

    for {
      async1Result <- asy1
      async2Result <- asy2

      async1Body <- Pagelet.readBody(async1Result)
      async2Body <- Pagelet.readBody(async2Result)

    } yield {
      Ok(views.html.home2(async1Body, async2Body))
    }
  }

}
```

So `Async2Controller` is very similar to `AsyncController` and `Pagelet.readBody` refers to this:

```
package Ui

import play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee
import play.api.mvc.{Codec, Result}
import play.twirl.api.Html
import scala.concurrent._

object Pagelet {

  def readBody(result: Result)(implicit codec: Codec): Future[Html] = {
    result.body.run(Iteratee.consume()).map(bytes => Html(new String(bytes, codec.charset)))
  }

}
```

And this is wherein the error lies - which is:

> value run is not a member of play.api.http.HttpEntity

I cannot find documentation on whether it needs to be injected or any indication that it has since been deprecated. **If someone has got an answer to this or a work-around please divulge**. Many thanks

Comment: It could be a problem with different versions. Video is pretty old.

Comment: Yes @Zemike - It's not a compatibility issue but yes the video is a few years old now. That's why I'm looking for an modern alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Iteratee` lib is deprecated and was replaced by `akka-stream`. You need to change the implementation of `readBody`:

```
def readBody(result: Result)(implicit mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext, codec: Codec): Future[Html] = {
  result.body.consumeData.map(byteString => Html(codec.decode(byteString))
}
```

You also need to change the dependencies of the controller to get a `Materializer`:

```
class AsyncHomeController @Inject() (as1: AsyncController, as2: Async2Controller)(actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext, mat: Materializer)
```

Edit: code updated

Comment: thanks - this seems close but I got this error ***not enough arguments for method consumeData*** so I did this  `def readBody(result: Result)(implicit mat: Materializer,  codec: Codec) : Future[Html] = {
    result.body.consumeData(mat).map(byteString => Html(codec.decode(byteString)))
  }` which then pulls up this error - ***Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext***. Of course if I add this as an implicit then it causes issues with the other implicit so I am struggling to get the right combination. It feels like we're definitely getting closer.

Comment: Thanks for the update - almost missed it. Implementing it like this brings up an error of ***could not find implicit value for parameter mat: akka.stream.Materializer*** despite importing it. So with this technique I'd have to pass `Materializer` as a parameter each time I call the function which doesn't seem right. I did however get this to work with by creating `implicit val system = ActorSystem(); implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()` within the *Object* and passing it within the method as before, i.e. `consumeData(mat)` but this also seems verbose

Comment: By doing so, you are creating an `ActorSystem` and a `Materializer` but play already has one. In your controller, you need to tell play to inject one: `class AsyncHomeController @Inject() (as1: AsyncController, as2: Async2Controller)(actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext, mat: Materializer)`

Comment: Yes that makes more sense. `consumeData` doesn't even have to pass a parameter now. Please update (edit) your answer to clarify this for others and I'll be happy to mark it as *answered*. Many thanks